# How to make a comment on Github Issue on creation (API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, github, github-api

I understand that I can submit an *initial* body/comment when I create a GitHub issue via API like so:

```
var issue = {
        "title": title,
        "body": bodytext,
        "assignees":[]
    };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: uploadURL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(issue)
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Is there a way to also put a separate comment on that issue during original creation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Issue API call returns issue number in it's response (https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue).

You can simply fire up another request just after the first one that creates a comment on that issue (https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment).

An example would probably look like this:

```
var issue = {
    "title": title,
    "body": bodytext,
    "assignees":[]
};

function createIssue(data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/repos/:owner/:repo/issues",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function (response) {
        // Return issue number from the response to the promise chain

        return response.number;
    });
}

function createComment(issueNumber, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/" + issueNumber + "/comments",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}

createIssue(issue).then(function (issueNumber) {
    return createComment(
        issueNumber,
        {
            // comment details
        }
    );
}).done(function () {
    // callback on successful issue & comment creation
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the createIssue call returned the issue number, excellent insight, thank you! I'll accept your answer just for that. With your code, I do happen to be getting the error: "TypeError: createIssue(...) is undefined" any thoughts?

Comment: Pasting it in the console works just fine, so I assume there has to be something wrong with how you've pasted or included this code in your project.